# How to compare polygons in different layers in QGIS 3.x?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, qgis-processing

To formulate my question with a concrete example: I have two multi-polygon layers of the same city.

- Layer A has polygons of the city divided in parts e.g. north, south, west, east.
- Layer B has smaller polygons that represent green e.g. trees, forests, parks and such.

Now I want to add a new column "city_part" in the attribute table of layer B. And likewise I'd want an either QGIS-expression- or Python-coded script, that can figure out in which polygon of layer A every single polygon of layer B lies.
So the concrete result would be a layer B in which every polygon's got a new attribute, telling whether it resides inside north, south, west or east. How can this be done?

Comment: a spatial join would also work. use the tool `join attributes by location`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of many:

- install [*refFunctions*](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/) plugin
- with your *greens* layer active

  - open *Field Calculator*
  - *Create a new field*

    - choose *Output field name* (e.g. `'city_part'`)
    - choose *Output field type* to match that of the *city parts* layers `id` column (ì.e. `Text`)
  - use expression:

    ```
    geomintersects( '<city_parts_layer_name>', '<city_parts_id_column_name>')
    ```

    and hit *Ok*

This assumes the *city parts* polygon `id` has the values `north, south, east, west`. It also assumes uniqueness of the intersections; if one of the smaller polygons intersects multiple *city parts*, it is internal order based which one will get assigned.

Comment: geomintersects() wasn't recognized, which plugin do I have to install to have this function?

Comment: Ops, forgot: those functions are part of the *refFunctions* plugin; see update for link